# How to move an element in a list in Haskell?

Tags: list, haskell

I'm reading through [Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/input-and-output) and reached a spot where I'm trying to move an element in a list to the head.  I've come up with what I think is the naive way and I'm curious if someone can show me what the experienced Haskell programmer would do instead.

In this example, I have a list of Integers and I want to move the element '4', which would be index '3', to the head of the list.

```
let nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
(nums !! 3) : delete (nums !! 3) nums
```

returns [4, 1, 2, 3, 5].

What do you think?

Comment: "delete" deletes the first occurrence of the given element, so it might remove the wrong element if there are duplicates...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I would do it this way:

```
move n as = head ts : (hs ++ tail ts)
   where (hs, ts) = splitAt n as
```

[`splitAt`](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#v:splitAt) splits a list at the given position, it returns the two parts that are created by the splitting (here `hs` and `ts`). The element that should be moved to the front is now at the beginning of `ts`. [`head ts`](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#v:head) returns just this first element of `ts`, [`tail ts`](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#v:tail) returns everything *but* that first element. The result of the function are just these parts combined in the right order: `hs` concatenated with `tail ts` and prepended by the element `head ts`.

Comment: toHead n l = let (xs, y:ys) = splitAt n l in y : xs ++ ys

Answer (score 11):

Experienced Haskellers hardly ever using list indexing. I'd use break to avoid repeated traversals (assuming you want to match on element '4', not index '3'):

```
case break (== 4)  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] of
    (a,x:xs) -> x:a ++ xs
    (a,xs)    -> a ++ xs
```

As in:

```
Prelude Data.List> case break (== 4)  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] of (a,x:xs) -> x:a ++ xs; (a,xs) -> a ++ xs
[4,1,2,3,5]
```

We can do the same with indexing via 'splitAt':

```
Prelude Data.List> case splitAt 3  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] of (a,x:xs) -> x:a ++ xs; (a,xs) -> a ++ xs
[4,1,2,3,5]
```

Comment: Yes, it's matching on element 4 not on index '3'. Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 9):

small modification on sth's solution:

```
toHead n xs = x : pre ++ post
  where (pre, x:post) = splitAt n xs
```

using pattern matching instead of `head` n `tail`

Comment: I think this is the easiest to understand solution. Nice touch with the pattern matching!

Answer (score 3):

There's also

```
toHead n l = l !! n : take n l ++ drop (n+1) l
```

which may be a little easier to follow than using `splitAt`.

Comment: isn't this slower than the splitAt version?

Comment: Not clear after the optimizer gets done with it.  Run with ghc -O and find out!

Comment: Would this do 2 passes over the list?

Answer (score 0):

What a co-incidence?
I was reading the same thing a few days back. Looked it up again & wrote it like following.

```
nums !! 3 : [x | x <- nums, (x == (num !! 3)) == False]
```

Comment: Two problems: First, duplicate elements are removed.  Second (less of a problem), the not equal operator is (/=), as opposed to ( (a == b) == False).

Comment: Good catch. As you can see, I am a beginner. Thanks for correcting :)